# Inserting with threads in C

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

i have 2 Threads which work on the same list with the same insert-function. Each Thread should insert it`s values (200 each) whenever it has the CPU.

I am confused now, how I can implement the "loop" which counts the inserts per thread?. I am using mutexes before and after i call the insert-function in the thread-function. So if i use a while loop in there, thread A would insert it's 200, then B it's 200. But thats not what i want here. Any Ideas how i can make each thread insert it's number as soon as they have the cpu, and stop, when they inserted 200?

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the threads, it is out of your control as far as cpu access is concerned. As far as counting the inserts for each thread, I would create a wrapper function for each thread that counts each separately.

```
void first_thread_wrapper()
{
    // while first_thread count < 200
    // lock
    // insert
    // increment first_thread count.
    // unlock
}

void second_thread_wrapper()
{
    // while second_thread count < 200
    // lock
    // insert
    // increment second_thread count.
    // unlock
}
```

Then you would give the first thread the first wrapper and the second thread the second wrapper. Obviously this is just pseudo code, but I think you can understand where I'm going.